# Java - how to sort an array based off of single int

Tags: java, sorting

Say I have an array as such:

```
[9, 7, 13, 24, 2, 16, 3, 10]
```

And I wanted to sort the array based off of the int 9, where all values less than 9 are to its left, and all values greater are to its right, could a version of selection sort be used?

A little stumped here

Comment: Confused - you want all the ints lower than 9 to its left, values higher than 9 to its right? Isn't that just a regular sort?

Comment: I think the question is to have to all elements less than 9 on the left and more than 9 on the right. There is no question of sorting amongst the elements on the left/right. Potentially, this is a one-step [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort Quicksort] problem.

Comment: Yea I was thinking more quicksort myself, where the int 9 is the pivot, and all values are sorted around the pivot

Comment: @Sean Are you still looking for a solution for this problem? I have a clean and extremely short solution to this problem.

Comment: @Sean , please check if my answer is what you need

Answer (score 1):

What you want should be something like one step of quick sort.

I modify a little so that you can pass an pivot needed as a parameter :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[]{9,7,13,24,2,16,3,10};
    System.out.println(partition(a,9));//use value 9 as pivot 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

}

private static int  partition(int[] a, int pivot){
    int pivotIndex = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){//find initial pivot Index
        if(a[i]==pivot) {
            pivotIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }


    int low = 0;
    int high = a.length-1;

    while(low<high){
        while(low<high&&a[high]>=pivot) high--;
        a[pivotIndex] = a[high];
        pivotIndex = high;

        while(low<high&&a[low]<=pivot) low++;
        a[pivotIndex] = a[low];
        pivotIndex= low;
    }

    //Actual pivotIndex finded
    a[pivotIndex] = pivot;

    return pivotIndex;
}
```

output:

```
3
[3, 7, 2, 9, 24, 16, 13, 10]
```